# Lazy load with Intersection Observer and offset

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, lazy-loading, intersection-observer

I'm upgrading a lazy load scroll mechanism with an intersection observer. My scroll mechanism looks like this:

```
    function setScrollListener(callBack) {
    document.addEventListener('scroll', throttle(callBack, 1000));
}
const state = {};
function checkInViewport() {
    const offset = 400;
    state.unrendered = state.unrendered.filter(el => {
        const visible = isInViewport(el, offset)
        if (visible) {
            display(el);
        }
        return !visible;
    });
}

setScrollListener(checkInViewport)
```

Without going too much into the weeds, `isInViewport` uses the offset provided and the `getClientBoundRect` of the element provided to determine if the element is near the viewport accounting for the offset. Essentially, is this element `400px` from the viewport? The method `display` simply displays the element.

Now using an intersection observer I have this:

```
const observeInViewport = (el, io) => {
    const { offset = 400 } = this.props;

    if (isInViewport(el, offset)) {
      display(el);
      io.unobserve(el);
    }
  }

const observationOpts = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: '0px',
    threshold: 0.1,
};
const lazyRef = document.getElementsByClassName("lazy");
const io = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => {
    observeInViewport(entry.target, io);
}, observationOpts);
[].slice.call(lazyRef).forEach(el => {
    io.observe(el);
});
```

I'm using the same `isInViewport` and `display` methods using the offset, but the offset won't trigger until the observer does. The observer is of course trigger by its threshold. I can't provide a negative threshold which would be ideal. I tried using the `documentElement` as my `root` option and then providing a `rootMargin` of `${(el.offsetTop - offset)}px 0px 0px 0px`. That is a string template, but the formatting here was messed up with the tick marks.

Can I achieve the same offset logic as I did with my scroll listener, but with  an intersection observable? Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: You'll need to put the offset in the rootMargin. You can also use `entry.intersectionRatio` instead of whatever you have in `isInViewport `. `threshold ` can be `0`.

Comment: @René, thank you! That did it. If you want to provide an example and an answer I will mark it and you can get the points. Maybe explain intersection ratio a bit.

Comment: Sorry, too lazy ;-) Glad I could help. You can add your own working version as answer and accept it. As for explaining, I think MDN does a great job already. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: @René lazy developers are the best developers :)